# when i set state , it gives output, but when i try to access elements inside state it gives undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This is my ReactJS code**

```
export default class HomeNew extends Component {

  state = {
    anime: [], // Initialize with an empty array
  };
  

  componentDidMount(){

    axios.get(URL_POPULAR).then((response) =>{
      const animeData = response.data.results.slice(0,3);
      //console.log(animeData)
      let slider_data = []
      for(let i = 0 ; i<animeData.length; i++){

        //console.log(animeData[i])

        axios.get(URL_INFO+`?id=${animeData[i].animeId}`).then((res) =>{
          //console.log(res.data)
          slider_data[i] = {
            "animeName" : res.data.title,
            "animeImage": res.data.image,
            "animeDes": res.data.description,
            "animeId" : animeData[i].animeId

          }
        } )
        
      }
      //console.log(slider_data)
      this.setState({ anime: slider_data })
      
    })

  }

  render() {

    const {anime} = this.state
    console.log(anime) //this gives array of 3 objects that i need
console.log(anime[0]) //this gives undefined


    return (
      <>
      i want to access those data here
but anime[0] gives undefined
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

When i print on console , anime state variable, it does gives 3 objects, but why when i do anime[0] it gives undefined
How to solve this, i am struggling for 3 hrs with this issue

Please HELP

Comment: Why `console.log()`? Why not just use your state data instead?

Comment: im using that just to test, if data is getting loaded or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are fetching data asynchronously, and mutating the `slider_data` reference. Since the for-loop is completely synchronous the `this.setState({ anime: slider_data })` runs before the GET requests resolve and the `slider_data` reference is saved into state. When the GET requests resolve the `slider_data` array is mutated. You are seeing this mutation exposed in the console logs in the `render` function when you examine them in the console.

## Solution

Rework the axios calls to wait until all the GET requests resolve ***then*** enqueue a state update to `anime`. Add a check in the `render` method to ensure `state.anime` is a populated array prior to access elements in it.

```
export default class HomeNew extends Component {
  state = {
    anime: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL_POPULAR)
      .then((response) => {
        const animeData = response.data.results.slice(0, 3);

        // Create array of requests
        const animeReqs = animeData.map(
          anime => axios.get(URL_INFO+`?id=${anime.animeId}`)
            .then(result => ({
              anime,
              result,
            }))
        );

        // Return array of requests
        return Promise.all(animeReqs);
      })
      .then(results => {
        // Map resolved values to new anime state
        const slider_data = results.map(({ anime, result }) => ({
          "animeName": result.data.title,
          "animeImage": result.data.image,
          "animeDes": result.data.description,
          "animeId": anime.animeId
        }));

        // Enqueue anime state update
        this.setState({ anime: slider_data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { anime } = this.state;
    console.log(anime); // this gives array of 3 objects that i need

    if (anime.length) {
      console.log(anime[0]); // <-- can log populated array element

      return (
        <>
          Access anime[0..3] data here
        </>
      );
    } else {
      // data not loaded yet
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an async/await problem. Try this instead. Additionally, mark `componentDidMount` with `async`. When you update the state, the view is rerendered, so you must be able to view the `slider_data`.

```
const response = await axios.get(URL_INFO+`?id=${animeData[i].animeId}`)
slider_data[i] = {
 "animeName" : response.data.title,
 "animeImage": response.data.image,
 "animeDes": response .data.description,
 "animeId" : animeData[i].animeId
}
```

Full code:

```
    async componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(URL_POPULAR).then((response) =>{
      const animeData = response.data.results.slice(0,3);
      //console.log(animeData)
      let slider_data = []
      for(let i = 0 ; i<animeData.length; i++){

        //console.log(animeData[i])

        const response = await axios.get(URL_INFO+`?id=${animeData[i].animeId}`)
       slider_data[i] = {
         "animeName" : response.data.title,
         "animeImage": response.data.image,
         "animeDes": response .data.description,
         "animeId" : animeData[i].animeId
        }
        
      }
      //console.log(slider_data)
      this.setState({ anime: slider_data })
      
    })

  }
```